Problems when Access Files get too large?
Is anyone aware of problems developing when Access files get too large. I am getting lots of random malfunctions as my 10-year old large database grows past 50 Mb.
I have tried to decompile my db, as recommended by experts, but I cannot find the location of my MSACCESS.EXE file on Windows 11 running Microsoft 365 and the latest version of Access. I cannot decompile at the command prompt. I found another solution by going back to an earlier version that works, but now I am getting random malfunctions again. Things just stop working. My latest issue is I can't change anything in the properties box. I am running a front-end/back-end system on my reasonably powerful laptop with many tables, and forms but not necessarily a lot of records in each table. This is a large, powerful database with a huge amount of VBA code. Can it be now TOO big?

do you always compile the accDB file to a accDE before deploying the FE (front end)? Normally a compact + repair will suffice, but often a de-compile can help. I would consider trying to deploy + use a accDE. Keep in mind, before creating the accDE, from VBA do a debug->compile to ensure you have no existing compile errors.

Access has a size limit of 2GB. 50 MB is not a big Access database. This is likely unrelated to the size. If you want better help, provide more details on exactly what is malfunctioning
